# Display Thumbnails In Icon View But Not In Compact View

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, nautilus, nemo, thumbnails

I use the Nemo file manager on Linux Mint 19 Tara. Usually I only work with the compact view without thumbnails (see image A), but occasionally I switch to icon view with thumbnails (see image B).

To switch from A to B I have to

1. Open the settings
2. Enable thumbnails
3. Change to icon view

and to switch back from B to A

4. Open the settings
5. Disable thumbnails
6. Change to compact view

[image: switching]

I'd like switch by just clicking the <kbd>icon view</kbd> (see image 3) or <kbd>compact view</kbd> (see image 6) buttons in the toolbar so that I have to click only once instead of seven times.

**Q:** Is there a way to enable thumbnails only in icon view?

I already checked for hidden dconf settings but couldn't find any. Maybe there is a plugin for what I need or a simple way to write one.

**Possible workarounds which would also be acceptable:**

- A toolbar button to toggle thumbnails on/off.
- Enable thumbnails only for icon sizes > ??px. I always use small icons in compact view and bigger icons/thumbnails in icon view.

**I'm *not*  interested in**

- showing thumbnails only in certain directories or for certain file types.
- using another file manger.

This question is tagged as [nautilus](/questions/tagged/nautilus) since Nemo is a fork of Nautilus. If there is a solution for Nautilus please post it. I may be able to use that solution for Nemo too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with Cinnamon 4.0, there is a new thumbnail setting and a new toolbar button. See [new features in Linux Mint 19.1](https://www.linuxmint.com/rel_tessa_cinnamon_whatsnew.php):

> You can configure Nemo to show thumbnails depending on the directory you are browsing. In this mode, a **thumbnail toggle button** appears in the toolbar and lets you decide whether or not show thumbnails for this particular directory.

[image: Enabling the setting]
[image: New thumbnail button]

The new button shows enables/disables thumbnails only for the current directory, but it is built in and probably the simplest way to get something similar to what you want.